# После миграции с хешкода на SO перестали приходить уведомления из подписанных вопросов.

Tags: дефект, поддержка

После миграции с хешкода на SO перестали приходить уведомления из подписанных вопросов. Проверил принимающие фильтры своего указанного почтового ящика там проблем нет. Подскажите причину моей беды.

Comment: Тут уже читали: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442 ?

Comment: @Nofate не работает это в моем случае, я так пробовал.

Comment: Подскажите, про какую именно подписку идет речь? На сколько я могу видеть, у вас сейчас есть подписка на _ваши_ вопросы и ответы, которая должна приходить один раз в день. Подписка «бюллетень сообщества» (например, на лучшие вопросы) у вас отключена.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky раньше если я задавал вопрос и мне давали ответы и комментарии то мне приходили письма об этом. А теперь не меньше двух лет с SO писем абсалютно вообще никаких не было, кроме письма с восстановлением пароля от моей уточной записи когда я ее восстанавливал.

Comment: @perfect Очень очень странно. Постараюсь разобраться в чем причина.

Comment: Уточнил. Почтовые нотификации отправляются только в том случае, если вы не прочитали уведомления на сайте (наверху слева, «входящие сообщения»). Если вы или, к примеру, какой–либо пользовательский скрипт, а так же мобильное приложение, получает их  и обновления отмечаются  прочитанными, они не будут отправляться по почте.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky а кто же тогда непрерывно третий год просматривает мои уведомления? Особенно в тот момент когда я сплю ))

Comment: К сожалению, не понял ваш комментарий. Пожалуйста, проведите эксперимент, получив нотификацию в вашем вопросе, не читайте ее и подождите сутки. Возможно, дело именно в том, что вы просматриваете сообщения.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky хорошо, если ЧП не будет попробую сутки не заходить на SO

Comment: Не заходить не обязательно, достаточно входящие не раскрывать. Скорее, заходить стоит, чтобы понять, что обновления действительно есть.

Comment: Подскажите, решилась ли проблема с подпиской?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky день добрый. не удалось проверить пока. нет возможности не пользоваться SO целые сутки. Постараюсь за наступающие выходные проверить.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky я бы вам посоветовал отключить проверку на мое посещение. если начнут приходить сообщения я сразу сообщу об этом.